# How can I download the svf file in the forge api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

How can I convert the file I uploaded to Forge to svf format and then download it to my own server?

I wanted to do these operations using your project "https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bucketsmanager-desktop/tree/master/bucket.manager". As a result, I downloaded it, but there are files in it that I will not use. The reason for this is that the load on the download process increases. I just want the "3d views" folder. Can you help with this?

Comment: The link you provided describes how to download the SVF, you should be able to download only the files you want, what is your problem ? It's hard to help you more because the SVF hierarchy can be different from a file to another, and we don't really know the files you want or not.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said, the structure of an SVF asset can vary depending on the input file format. For more details on how to download the SVF (or just some of its parts), take a look at the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) library, specifically the [SvfDownloader](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/svf/downloader.ts). It parses the actual SVF file to identify all the additional assets (e.g., geometry files, textures, property database files, etc.) that need to be downloaded as well.