# Aps viewer Query

Tags: autodesk-forge

1. Code to Download link for aps viewer output file
2. Similarly conversion code for viewer SVF output to step file and to get download link for that output

I need solution for the above mention questions related to APS Viewer APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar Stackoverflow question that might help answer your question: [How can I download the svf file in the forge api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690223/how-can-i-download-the-svf-file-in-the-forge-api/73811117#73811117)

You'll find the link to some sample code on how to download your model file in APS.